# Problemas ao usar o test runner do NodeJS em um projeto NestJS

Tags: node.js, typescript

Olá! Estou tentando rodar testes na minha aplicação NestJS usando o test runner nativo do NodeJS, mas estou tendo alguns problemas.

1 - Não consigo rodar vários arquivos de teste com o script `"test": "node -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register --test ./test"`. A única forma que funciona é passando o caminho até um arquivo específico, tipo `"test": "node -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register --test ./test/auth.spec.ts"`, mas assim eu teria que criar um script para cada arquivo de teste.

2 - Não sei o porquê, mas objeto "assert" é undefined durante o teste. Eu vi muitas pessoas importando como `import assert from "node:assert"` ou `import assert from "node:assert/strict"`, mas se eu tento importar dessa maneira ocorre o erro `TypeError [Error]: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'strictEqual')`. Eu tive que importar como `import { strict as assert } from "node:assert"` e assim funcionou, mas os outros imports são bem melhores.

Esse é o código do teste caso alguém queira ver, mas ainda não terminei ele.

```
import * as request from 'supertest';
import { INestApplication } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Test } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { AppModule } from '@src/app.module';
import { describe, before, after, it } from 'node:test';
import { strict as assert } from 'node:assert';
import { SignupDTO } from '@src/entities/user/user.type';

describe('Auth', () => {
  let app: INestApplication;

  before(async () => {
    const moduleRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [AppModule],
    }).compile();

    app = moduleRef.createNestApplication();

    await app.init();
  });

  it('/POST signup', async () => {
    const body = new SignupDTO();

    body.name = 'Miguel O Hara';
    body.email = 'spiderman2099@testmail.com';
    body.password = 'spiderman2099';
    body.password_confirmation = 'spiderman2099';

    await request(app.getHttpServer())
      .post('/auth/signup')
      .send(body)
      .then((response)=>{
        assert.strictEqual(response.statusCode, 200);
      });
  });

  after(async () => {
    await app.close();
  });
});
```

Se alguém estiver trabalhando com o test runner nativo do NodeJs em um projeto NestJS, eu adoraria receber algumas dicas. Comecei a utilizar o node test runner  ao invés do Jest recentemente, então sou bem novato nisso.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Baseado no que Jay McDoniel fez [aqui](https://github.com/jmcdo29/nest-lab/blob/main/packages/fastify-multer/test/index.spec.ts), eu criei um arquivo responsável por importar todos os arquivos de teste e executá-los.

Na minha pasta de testes eu tenho isso:
[imagem da pasta "test"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VG7iR.png)

No meu arquivo `run.ts` eu tenho isso:

```
import { join } from 'node:path';
import { readdir } from 'node:fs/promises';

const testFiles = [];
const testDir = join(__dirname);

(async () => {
  try {
    const files = await readdir(testDir);

    files.forEach(function (file) {
      if (file.match(/\.test\.ts$/)) {
        testFiles.push(import(join(testDir, file)));
      }
    });

    await Promise.all(testFiles);
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('Unable to scan directory: ' + err);
  }
})();
```

No meu arquivo `auth.test.ts` eu basicamente adicionei `export default` antes da função `describe`:

```
import * as request from 'supertest';
import { INestApplication } from '@nestjs/common';
import { Test } from '@nestjs/testing';
import { AppModule } from '@src/app.module';
import { describe, before, after, it } from 'node:test';
import * as assert from 'node:assert/strict';
import { SignupDTO } from '@src/entities/user/user.type';

export default describe('Auth', () => {
  let app: INestApplication;

  before(async () => {
    const moduleRef = await Test.createTestingModule({
      imports: [AppModule],
    }).compile();

    app = moduleRef.createNestApplication();

    await app.init();
  });

  it('/POST signup', async () => {
    const body = new SignupDTO();

    body.name = 'Miguel O Hara';
    body.email = 'spiderman2099@testmail.com';
    body.password = 'spiderman2099';
    body.password_confirmation = 'spiderman2099';

    await request(app.getHttpServer())
      .post('/auth/signup')
      .send(body)
      .then((response)=>{
        assert.strictEqual(response.statusCode, 200);
      });
  });

  after(async () => {
    await app.close();
  });
});
```

E no script apenas coloquei o caminho para o arquivo `run.ts`:

```
"test": "node -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register --test ./test/run.ts"
```

Sobre o import do objeto assert. Enquanto eu fazia o código do arquivo `run.ts`, aprendi que devo importar a função exata que eu quero, assim como fiz com o import da função `join` do `node:path` no arquivo `run.ts`, ou eu posso simplesmente importar tudo como "alguma coisa", assim como fiz no arquivo auth.test.ts:

```
import * as assert from 'node:assert/strict';
```